# Facebook Application SSL Change - AJAX Flash/Server Data Security

Tags: javascript, facebook, ssl, oauth-2.0, amf

We are in the process of migrating (yup a bit late huh) of our apps to handle SSL fully (rather than just the monetization portions).

We've looked at a few other application developer integrations and it looks like the Flash-server data requests are under normal HTTP requests (well, in AMF).

Any ideas if both JS AMF requiring HTTPS transport?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the JS AMF is still in pre-alpha state per the project's home page.  I'm not sure it is being developed for anymore, as the last update was in Jul 09.  A very long time ago.  I would suggest using the latest Facebook Javascript SDK and go from there.